# Integrate:$ \int (x^2+\cos^2 x)(\csc^2 x)/(1+x^2) dx$

Tags: integration

Integrate: $[x^2+\cos^2x]\csc^2 x/(1+x^2)  dx$
How to make the substitution here. I have tried to make the substitution as $\tan^{-1}x =t$ 
But got stuck further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $x^2 + \cos^2x = (x^2+1)+(\cos^2x-1)$, and split it in two integrals.